# Fastest and best way to write huge data in XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, performance, file-handling

We are using FileOutputStream to writing data into the XML file in the Java but this way is taking longer time. Can anybody suggest an example with that we can write data into XML file better than below approach.?

```
/**
 * This function output data into file
 * 
 * @param result
 * @param fileName
 * @param folderName
 */
private static void writeResultToFile(String result, String fileName, String folderName, String extension) {
    try {
        if (result != null && !result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            byte bWrite[] = result.getBytes();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(folderName + "/" + fileName + "." + extension);
            for (int x = 0; x < bWrite.length; x++) {
                os.write(bWrite[x]); // Writes the bytes
            }
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        /*
         * Logging
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `result.equalsIgnoreCase("")`? Do you think, case matters for an empty string? There’s obviously no difference to `result.equals("")` but you should just use `result.isEmpty()` to express the actual intent.

Comment: Yes, that can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write it byte by byte, use the write method taking a `byte[]` as argument. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A- for details.

Also, since you have a string (i.e. character data) to begin with consider using a `Writer`.

Comment: To emphasise that second point: using result.getBytes() will get you the content of the string in an encoding that does not necessarily match the encoding specified in the XML declaration of the file. If the two encodings are different, no-one will be able to read the file.

Comment: And the OP should use [`try(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for managing a resource. But even better, just use [`Files.writeString(Path.get(folderName, fileName + "." + extension), result);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) to solve all issues at once, in a simple one-liner.